# How to force a location update after clicking on a Refresh menu button?

Tags: android, google-maps

I just wanted to know if it is possible to force a location update in order to get the position of the mobile once I click on the refresh item in the menu.

Here is the code below that I found in a forum, and I want to add a new function.

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MapLocator extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

     private MapView mapView;
     private LocationManager lm;
     private MapController mc;
     private double lat = 0;
     private double lng = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.setZoom(14);


    int FIVE_MINUTES = 5 /*Minutes*/ * 60 /*sec per min*/ * 1000 /*ms per sec*/;
    lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  FIVE_MINUTES, 0, this);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,  FIVE_MINUTES, 0, this);


     Drawable drawable= this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loc_seven);
     ListItimizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new ListItimizedOverlay(drawable);
     GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(33000000,84000000);
     OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Hello from", "Tahiti");
     itemizedoverlay.addOverlayItem(overlayitem);
     mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);

}

 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
 {
 return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S)
     {
         mapView.setSatellite(!mapView.isSatellite());
         return true;
     }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
 {
     Log.d("msg","1");

     lat = location.getLatitude();
     lng = location.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(
                getBaseContext(),
                "Location change to : Latitude = " + lat + " Longitude = "
                    + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
     mc.animateTo(p);
     mc.setCenter(p);
     mc.setZoom(14);
     Drawable drawable= this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loc_seven);
     ListItimizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new ListItimizedOverlay(drawable);
     OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "", "");
     itemizedoverlay=  (ListItimizedOverlay ) mapView.getOverlays().get(0);
     itemizedoverlay.clear();
     itemizedoverlay.addOverlayItem(overlayitem);
     mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);

 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
 {
 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
 {
 }

 @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
 {
 }


  //Menu with 2 items Refresh and exit

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu2) {


        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menumap, menu2);

        return true;
     }


      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


          switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.refresh:
                /* 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 code to add in order to refrech the location and position the mobile  
on the map using the drawable in the itemizedoverlay. I have tried this : 
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  0, 0, this);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
and nothing is changed i still see the old position on the map

and I have tested the app on a sony Ericsson Xperia x10.

I am using google API 10 if this might help.



------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

                return true;

           case R.id.exit:

               finish();
               return true;
         }
         return false;}





}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 5):

This code should do the trick:

```
        lm.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
        Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        lat = loc.getLatitude();
        lng = loc.getLongitude();
```

Comment: Those were just variables I used when I implemented this.  I will update it to yours

Comment: Let me know if there are errors with this code, if it does not work.

Comment: This is not the right answer. The method getLastKownLocation doesn't force a location update. It just returns the cached location on the device. If there's none, null is returned.